# Accessing models from outside rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey I am creating a **rails 3 engine** and trying to access a model in the application that is mounting the engine.

```
module MyEngine
  class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @users = User.all
    end
```

If I call the following then it gives me the error:

**Could not find table 'my_engine_users'** - Its automatically looking for the namespaced version that would exist if the model was inside the engine, but in this case its defined in the app that uses the engine.

**If I call ::User.all instead of User.all then everything works**, it looks a bit strange though. Is this valid ruby or is there a better way to get ahold of the Object?

Answer (score 0):

So if I get your question right, you have a model in your engine looking something like this:

```
module MyEngine
  class User
  end
end
```

If the assumption above is right, you can just set the table name via `table_name=` **in the model**

```
module MyEngine
  class User
    self.table_name = 'users'
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately that wont work because I dont have access to the User.rb file. That is defined by the user who is implementing my rails engine.

Comment: Ok, but you do have a user class as a model somewhere in your `MyEngine` module now, probably for testing purposes, right? Because your error would not happen if calling `User` where not ambiguous. That means: If you test your engine, create the test user class outside the `MyEngine` model, and you should be fine.